# Where to find Image Database for evaluating image fusion Algorithms

Tags: image, evaluation, fusion

I need some sample images (different left-blurred and right-blurred RGB images) to evaluate image fusion algorithms. A sample image is in this paper ( link to paper ), and it seems it used 10 sample images. Any idea, help or a link to such images will be deeply appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You may find something here.... https://github.com/caesar0301/awesome-public-datasets

Comment: Excuse me, there was not any sample image in the file in the link!

Comment: Sorry! Click `View all of README`